# Exception while inserting multiple user input values to Mongo db collection

Tags: java, mongodb, crud

I am writing a basic CREATE and READ operation in JAVA-MongoDB. I am trying to insert the records entered by user to the database and read the same.

This is how my current code looks-

```
Create.java-
import com.mongodb.Block;
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.*;
import com.mongodb.client.model.InsertManyOptions;
import org.bson.Document;

import javax.print.Doc;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Create {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static String inputValue;


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWD@CLUSTER.mongodb.net/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

        System.out.println("Enter any string:");
        inputValue = scanner.nextLine();

        //Creating a collection
        database.createCollection("students");
        //Preparing a document
        Document document = new Document("name", inputValue);
        //Inserting the created documents
        List<Document> list = new ArrayList<Document>();
        for(Document d: list) {
            list.add(d);
        }
        database.getCollection("students").insertMany(list, new InsertManyOptions().ordered(false));
        System.out.println("Document inserted successfully");
        mongoClient.close();

    }
}

Read.java
import com.mongodb.Block;
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.*;
import org.bson.Document;

import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Read {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static String inputValue;


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWD@CLUSTER.mongodb.net/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");




        // Read Data from MongoDB
        //Creating a collection object
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("students");
        //Retrieving the documents
        FindIterable<Document> iterDoc = collection.find();
        Iterator it = iterDoc.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }

        mongoClient.close();
       // findIterable.forEach(printBlock);


    }
}
```

I am able to insert and read one record successfully. But when I try to enter some different input in the prompt it throws the below exception-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error code pretty much says it all.

**Collection "students" already exists in this DB**

```
//Creating a collection
database.createCollection("students");
```

This is the part of your code that is correct, but must be run only once, because if the collection exists, an Exception will be thrown...

So just remove it and keep in mind that creation of Collections through code throws errors when they already exist.

And you do know that the list that you are inserting is empty right?

```java
Document document = new Document("name", inputValue); // This is your created document

//Inserting the created documents
List<Document> list = new ArrayList<Document>(); // This is a list that CAN contain Documents but it is initialized and it is EMPTY
for(Document d: list) // The for loop will not be executed at all since the list is empty...
{
    list.add(d);
}
```

Add your document to your list.

```java
list.add(document);
```

The enhanced `for` loop is used to traverse the `List`. I am not sure but you had in mind but you can check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp) to learn about it.

Comment: Thank you! I did realise that my list is empty but I kinds thought I need to iterate over. I am realising my mistake now. Also, I am curious to know why do we need to remove the line that creates collection. I just removed it and my code works perfectly fine but I am wondering how will Mongo know which collection to refer to as you can see that's the only place where I am creating collections.

Comment: You have to remove that line since the Collection is already there, you do not need to create it over again. Or more precisely (Mongo won't let you). Mongo will know which collection to refer to since you use: ` database.getCollection("students").insertMany()` You see that `getCollection()` part, that one does the magic.

Comment: And please upvote and accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, I will. So, that means we dont need to manually create the collection. I might have to read this more. I thought getollection will only be valid if have created the collection before.

Comment: Mongo has a good feature. When you try to insert data in a non existing DB/Collection, it will be automatically created for you. Try inserting to a DB which does not exist or a collection that does not exist and you will notice :)